# Не удается сохранить данные измененные в программе в томах docker

Tags: c#, sqlite, docker, docker-compose

У меня есть проект телеграмм бот. В нем я подключаюсь к базе данных **sqlite**

```
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($@"Data Source=c:\mr\tg\tg\db\reminderd.db");
```

И с помощью запросов вношу изменения в базу, все работает. Но при развертывании в **docker** с помощью **docker-compose up** данные которые изменились в прошлом развертывании исчезают. Вот мой **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    todo-sqlite-data:

services:
  app:
    build: ./tgreminder

    environment:
    - IDENTIFICATOR=2125884152:AAFXfwQtBhfK0i8FayW5fnnlYE_e5hym8Tc
    depends_on:
      - sqlite3

  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
    - todo-sqlite-data:/root/db/
    tty: true
```

Я заметил, проверяя тома через **docker volume**, что после каждого перезапуска:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

время создания тома изменяется на текущее.
Может дело в том что я создаю подключение в программе к локальной базе, которая находится в моем проекте **в папке db**, а следует к базе который находится в **volume**?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно локально хранить файлы бд. В вашем случае volume подключен к temp хранилищу докера. То есть примерно так может быть:

```
sqlite3:
    ...
    volumes:
        - ./local_db_folder/:/root/db/
```

Comment: Получается, если у меня docker compose.yml находиться в папке /mr/, а база в папке /mr/tg/tg/db, будет выглядеть так? volumes:
        - ./tg/tg/db/:/root/db/

Comment: По идее да, при запуске проекта, докер поместит вашу локальную бд внутрь контейнера, заменив (в теории там ничего нет) данные.

Comment: Вроде должно работать, но все также. Видимо проблема в установке соединения с бд в программе, либо у меня докер неправильно работает.